# RequestEntityTooLargeException for a lambda invoke

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a lambda function calling another lambda function using the lambda [invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property) method:

```
lambda.invoke({
    FunctionName: 'MyOtherLambda',
    InvocationType: 'Event',
    Payload: myBigObject
}, callback);
```

I am using `InvocationType: 'Event'` to stop this first lambda without waiting for `MyOtherLambda` to finish. The thing is I get  the following error:

> RequestEntityTooLargeException: 179206 byte payload is too large for the Event invocation type (limit 131072 bytes)

Removing `InvocationType: 'Event'` indeed makes it work but the lambda keeps running for nothing. I tried to use the deprecated [invokeAsync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invokeAsync-property) method but this leads to the same error.

How can I pass a large Payload without waiting for the second lambda to complete and why is the size of the Payload limited when using `InvocationType: 'Event'` ?

Answer (score 5):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) you are limited to 256 KB payload size using `Event` invocation type.  `RequestResponse` invocation type (the default) allows for 6 MB.

- One way you can get around this is to upload the file to S3 in your first lambda, then pass the bucket and key as the payload to the 2nd lambda.
- You could also have the 2nd lambda's trigger be the [upload to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html).

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. But when I do ``` JSON.stringify(payload).length``` I got **112193** while error shows **170412 byte** . Can you tell me why is that?